# Tailwind: Change the bg-gradient of div with dark mode

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm learning tailwind and I have this div :

```
<div class="mt-5 border border-gray-300 p-2 bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-100 via-purple-50 to-gray-50 rounded-lg mb-8 p-4 dark:bg-black">
```

And in dark mode my background is still the original gradient (my dark mode is working)

I want a black background in dark mode.

I noticed that If I did this :

```
<div class="mt-5 border border-gray-300 p-2 bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-100 via-purple-50 to-gray-50 rounded-lg mb-8 p-4 bg-gradient-to-b from-green-200 via-pink-100 to-red-500">
```

It's the second gradient (bg-gradient-to-b from-green-200 via-pink-100 to-red-500) which is used.

But if I did this :

```
<div class="mt-5 border border-gray-300 p-2 bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-100 via-purple-50 to-gray-50 rounded-lg mb-8 p-4 bg-black">
```

That's not the bg-black which is used but the bg-gradient-to-b.

So maybe it's linked :)

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the background color in dark mode is black, you can try adding the `dark:bg-black` class directly to your `div`.

```
   <div class="mt-5 border border-gray-300 p-2 bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-100 via-purple-50 to-gray-50 rounded-lg mb-8 p-4 dark:bg-black">
```

Comment: Maybe I explained it badly but i dit it and it's not working

Comment: okay check again , i've edited the code.

Comment: You tell me to add dark:bg-black but I said it's not working and it's the subject of my post my friend

Comment: Ok thank you chat gpt but I told you that my other components are working in dark mode

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing this issue because bg-gradient works like adding a background image to a div. Whereas, bg-black is just background-color. Gradient takes priority over background color.

So I tested your code and added `dark:bg-none` to clear out the gradient set for light mode and it works. Here's the updated code:

```
<div class="mt-5 border border-gray-300 p-2 bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-100 via-purple-50 to-gray-50 rounded-lg mb-8 p-4 dark:bg-black dark:bg-none">
</div>
```

Edit: [Tailwind Play Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XVZl4kXlqB)
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that but it seems that it doesnt work

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you but I've edited the answer to add the Tailwind Play CDN (with screenshot) for you to see. Or maybe you're trying to achieve something else?

Comment: it's really weird... all my components are working but not this one.. How do you switch to dark mode in tailwind play ? On your link when I click on dark mode I still have the gradient background... But maybe it's the dark mode for the website not for my code